# CCV code to Customer information manager on authorize.net

Tags: credit-card, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I implemented CIM(customer information manager) on authorize.net
My confusion is:
When to supply CCV number?
1) While creating customer profile(as it in input parameters list of createCustomerProfileRequest )?
2) Or, while doing transaction?

In my site, customer once creates his profile on authorize.net, and later on after a few days, I (Merchant) get payments as I do have customer profile id.

Now I don't want to call my customer to give me his CCV code for transaction, so point 2 is not possible within the way I implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You provide the CVV number when you create the payment profile. It's not possible to provide when charging against the profile because the API call does not allow for it.